# how to add subjects in same days column not multiple

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the records below.  I want to show subjects when Monday in column all subjects appear on Monday with start time and end time.  How do I do this?

```
SELECT t.teacher_name, tci.class_name, tsb.Subject_Name, tdn.DaysName, 
       tss.subject_start, tss.subject_end
FROM   tblsubjectSchedule tss
INNER JOIN tblsubjects tsb ON tss.subject_id = tsb.Idx
INNER JOIN tblclassinfo tci ON tss.class_id = tci.Idx
INNER JOIN tbldaysnames tdn ON tss.days_id = tdn.Idx 
INNER JOIN tblteacher t ON tss.techer_id = t.Idx
WHERE tss.class_id = 2 AND t.school_id = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please format your query.
Also, can you please show some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attachment is not completely clear. Are you going to ignore teacher_name on result?
In your screenshot you haven't included 'samad teacheer' on Monday results. You want the query only for Monday date?

If you only focus on class and days and date, I got below. please refer the attachment.Let me know if it works for you and accept my answer.
 [image]

```
SELECT t1.class_name,t1.daysname,
       subject_name =REPLACE( (SELECT  (subject_name+'-start:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, subject_start, 120)+'-End:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, subject_end, 120)) AS [data()]
           FROM [practice].[dbo].[test] t2
          WHERE t2.daysname = t1.daysname
          ORDER BY subject_name
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), ' ', ';')
      FROM [practice].[dbo].[test] t1
      GROUP BY daysname,class_name ;
```

You could also add teacher name to the schedule column: see the attachment
[image]

```
SELECT t1.class_name,t1.daysname,
       schedule =REPLACE( (SELECT  (teacher_name+'-'+subject_name+'-start:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, subject_start, 120)+'-End:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, subject_end, 120)) AS [data()]
           FROM [practice].[dbo].[test] t2
          WHERE t2.daysname = t1.daysname
          ORDER BY subject_name
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), ' ', ';')
      FROM [practice].[dbo].[test] t1
      GROUP BY daysname,class_name ;
```

Here is the query only for the 'Monday'

```
SELECT t1.class_name,t1.daysname,
       schedule =REPLACE( (SELECT  (teacher_name+'-'+subject_name+'-start:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, subject_start, 120)+'-End:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, subject_end, 120)) AS [data()]
           FROM [practice].[dbo].[test] t2
          WHERE t2.daysname = t1.daysname
          ORDER BY subject_name
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), ' ', ';')
      FROM [practice].[dbo].[test] t1 where daysname='Monday'
      GROUP BY daysname,class_name ;
```